# How to fix runtimewarning with pyrren python that stops the code from executing?

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm currently building an LM Ann using pyrren

```
#gradient
g = np.dot(J.transpose(),e)
#calculate scaled inverse hessian
try:
  G = np.linalg.inv(JJ+dampfac*np.eye(net['N']))
  #scaled inverse hessian except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
  # Not invertible. Go small step in gradient direction
  w_delta = 1.0/1e10 * g
else:
  # calculate weight modification
  w_delta = np.dot(-G,g)
```

but I get this warning sometimes

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyrenn.py:722: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply   G = np.linalg.inv(JJ+dampfac*np.eye(net['N'])) #scaled inverse hessian .
```

Does anyone how I can get around this?
Whenever I bump into this the program just stuck.

Comment: Can you post your code from pyrenn.py file around line 722. Could be helpful for some more context

Comment: pyrenn.py is provided by yabata(available on :)
Here is a snapshot of line 722 from the code
#gradient
   g = np.dot(J.transpose(),e)
   
   #calculate scaled inverse hessian
   try:
    G = np.linalg.inv(JJ+dampfac*np.eye(net['N'])) #scaled inverse hessian
   except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
    # Not invertible. Go small step in gradient direction
    w_delta = 1.0/1e10 * g
   else:
    # calculate weight modification
    w_delta = np.dot(-G,g)

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. You'll want to update your question with this code. Comments are a little hard to read, and have no formatting.